# PHP compare variable with a plus sign

Tags: php

If I have a value of 1+ in a VARCHAR column in a MySQL table, how can I compare this variable in php?

```
 if ($days=="1+")
```

does not appear to work, so how to compare it including the plus sign?

Comment: Please explain your problem more fully.

Comment: in my mysql table i have a column DAYS, it has field types of varchar, and is filled with numbers 1 till 30, but also 1+. so, 1, 1+, 2, 3 etc.   now i want to echo something when the value in DAYS is 1+, but i cannot use an IF as above since it sees it as just 1, not 1+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in your database if you **days** column as **varchar**, than you will get the exact value (even with +), so:

```
if($days == "1+") is true
```

a more complete code for you to try

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT days FROM table");
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) ) {
    if($row["days"] == "1+") echo 'found' . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Please don't write answers with old `mysql_` functions. [Find out why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your query?  I have a feeling that you've misidentified the issue.

That said, have you tried typecasting?

```
if ((string) $days == "1+")
```

Comment: i think i did something wrong earlier, it seems to work now as it should. thank you!